# PHP stdout on Apache

Tags: php, apache

Using PHP 5.3 as php5_module in Apache 2.2 on Windows 7.

Where does stdout go in the above configuration?

Tested with following code:

```
<?php
    $stdout = fopen('php://stdout', 'w');
    fwrite($stdout, "stdout<br />\n");

    $output = fopen('php://output', 'w');
    fwrite($output, "output<br />\n");
?>
```

This only displays `output` in the browser. What happens to stdout?

Comment: Check the apache and/or php logs, since this is referencing the PHP process's `stdout` stream, I'm guessing that's where it's being sent.

Comment: Not in apache or php logs. PHP stderr output is in apache log.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

As the manual shows on the [php:// wrappers](http://www.php.net/manual/en/wrappers.php.php) manual page:

> *php://output* is a write-only stream that allows you to write to the
>   output buffer mechanism in the same way as **print** and **echo**.

So if you want to write output to the browser, use `php://output`

On the other hand, `php://stdout`

> allow direct access to the corresponding input or output stream of the
>   PHP process.

In the case of Apache, this output is Apache's stdout handle which is generally never seen anywhere because this is console output for Apache and it is usually run in the background.  If you were to run Apache in the foreground on your console, anything you write to `php://stdout` would be visible on the console.  Since Apache is run in the background, no `stdout` data is captured or written anywhere normally.

To test this, follow these steps:

- Run Apache in the foreground (e.g. `/usr/local/apache2/bin/httpd -D FOREGROUND -k start`)
- Leave the console window open
- Run your script from the browser
- Look for your `stdout` output on the console.